# How to plot the mean and variance of a conditional Gaussian Distribution?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I found the attached image on the website, http://www.cvlibs.net/projects/gausspro/.

How can I generate this nice image in latex?
How can I generate it with specific values? based on an internal calculation?

[image]

Comment: `tikz` plus a lot of elbow grease.

Comment: Welcome! Right now, this is a do-it-all-for-me. As such, it may get answered or may not. You'll stand a better chance asking for help with something cuter. Ducks are especially popular, but cats and donkeys can be successful if you put your request in the right way. I'm a sucker for trees myself. Maybe you'd like a tree instead? Then I'll think I ought not answer, but probably will anyway. Failing a change of desiderata, I'm afraid you might have to try doing your work yourself and asking specific questions (with problematic code) if you get stuck.

Comment: Actually, we already have Gaussians to get you started ....

Comment: Thank you cfr. I saw that link but I was more curious if I can write an internal function that represent the conditional density which can get values and plot the marginal distribution as in the figure attached. Thank you for your long comment and I'm sorry that I gave you the feeling that I was looking for someone to do the work for me. That not what I'm looking for.